# WPF Textbox Preview events related

Tags: wpf, textbox, events, preview

I have a WPF textbox, and perform the following actions

1. Enter text as "12345"
2. Move cursor between 3 and 4 (using arrow or
   mouseclick)
3. Enter 0 (so Text is now "123045")

Which event/eventargs can tell me that 0 was typed at location 4.
I need to know this at Preview level so that I can reject the character 0 based on the prefixed and suffixed digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PreviewTextInput event you can use the TextBox's **CaretIndex** property to know the location where input is being typed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PreviewTextInput event. (see [here](http://karlhulme.wordpress.com/2007/02/15/masking-input-to-a-wpf-textbox/) for a complete example)

Comment: PreviewTextInput doesnt tell me the position at which the new character will be typed.